# Resizing the center column only for custom Prestashop pages

Tags: prestashop-1.5

so I need to make custom pages for Prestashop 1.5.6 which includes the top bar menu and footer but which doesnt include the left and right columns bar and menus, etc. So I created a controller like this,

```
class ElectronicaControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'electronica';
    public $page_name = 'Electronica';


    public function initContent()
    {
        $this->display_column_left = false;
        $this->display_column_right = false;

        parent::initContent();

        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'electronica.tpl');
    }

}
```

and what I get it's the left and right columns disappear, but the center column is cornered at the left and it doesnt fill the whole page size but it's 573px . How can I get the center column to be the size of the whole page only for custom pages? (the center column needs to remain the same for the regular prestashop main page , etc. obviously where the left and right blocks are present)

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make responsive center column. Column 100% not 573 px. As I remember 1.5 version is not responsive. So make center column max-width: 100%, height: auto and it should be responsive.

Comment: thanks, I solved it by dynamically changing the css when it's custom page but good to know